# Give a random age number between 0-9 Java

Tags: java

So I'm currently a beginner programmer trying to slove some basic programming tasks. But I dont understand why My code is wrong. In eclipse everyting works. It's a coding problem from codewars.com

Introduction:
You ask a small girl,"How old are you?" She always says, "x years old", where x is a random number between 0 and 9.

Write a program that returns the girl's age (0-9) as an integer.

Assume the test input string is always a valid string. For example, the test input may be "1 year old" or "5 years old". The first character in the string is always a number.

```
package headfirstjava;
import java.util.Random;



public class do_something5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        {
        int min =1;
        int max =9;
        int age1 = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)+ min);
        int age2 = (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)+ min);
        System.out.println("I'm "+ age1+ " Old");
    }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code works fine on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php what are you stuck on?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number, or how to parse a number embedded in a string? Edit to ask a very specific question.

Comment: Tip: More convenient random number code is `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1 , 10 )`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't understand the problem asked. Here the **input** of the program is the string "x years old" and you have to return "x" as an integer :

```
return Integer.parseInt(input.substr(0,1))
```

Comment: Both answers were right ,but i don't know why it showed up wrong, :/ guess they are very specific with the answers you can write . thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is.
Try this if the problem is with generating random number:

```
    // create random object
    Random ran = new Random();

    // Print next int value
    // Returns number between 0-9
    int nxt = ran.nextInt(10);

    // Printing the random number 
    // between 0 and 9
    System.out.println
    ("Random number between 0 and 9 is : " + nxt);
```

Also check out [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class in java! (Sry if this doesn't help)

Comment: Alternatively you can use the new API from "java.util.random" package:    RandomGenerator.getDefault().nextInt(10);

Comment: Read and understand the requirement: `Write a program that returns the girl's age (0-9) as an integer.` The questioner did not understand the requirement. You could address this issue in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract a number from a specific string format (means you know where the number you are looking for is) use the Character.getNumericValue(string.charAt(0)) method.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
System.out.println("How old are you?");
String s= scanner.nextLine();  
char c=s.charAt(0);
System.out.println("1st character is: "+ Character.getNumericValue(c) );
```

This is the simplest form that you can go. I suggest you go through w3schools.com for the basics.